# How to unwind segue from 3rd view controller to 1st? Using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

Views:  1 -> 2 -> 3
I have a button on the 3rd view controller, dragged it to exit button and picked unwind segue (function in 1st controller) But when i press the button app just crashes.

Using xcode 6

In 1st(Home) Controller

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // empty for now
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Any navigation controllers? Modal or push segues?

Comment: just buttons on the page. segue 1->2 is custom to show a transition. All Push segues